# Fourier transform of an equation of Matrices

Tags: fourier-transform, mathematics

I am confronted by an equation of the form

\begin{equation}
A[\omega] = (-i \textbf{1} \omega - i C[\omega])^{-1} \left( -i D[\omega] -i E[\omega] F[\omega] \right)
\end{equation}
where capital letters deonte matrices and the $[\omega]$ says that $M[\omega]$ is  Fourier transform of $M(t)$. Now I want to know how can one take an *inverse Fourier transform* of the above equation? That is, what would be the expression of $A(t)$?

Comment: I'm assuming you are looking for an expression in terms of the the original matrices $C(t),D(t),E(t),F(t)$. The product is simply replaced by a convolution. However, there is no general formula for the Fourier transform of the (multiplicative) inverse of a function. You'll need to calculate it directly. Note however that for scalars, it is less expensive to multiply and Fourier transform rather than Fourier transform and convolve. In the case of matrices, perhaps sparsity of the matrices in time will tip the scale in the other direction, so you should test both approaches.

Comment: Would [math.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: Yeah, already posted it on Mathematics, but no response!